# Dark spot after texture bake

Tags: baking

I'm using SimpleBake to bake a room to a texture, but I get a dark spot on the couch.

Params:

- Engine: Cycles
- Samples: 8192
- Bake type: combined
- Colour space: filmic log
- Denoise (Cycles)
- Bake / Output at 8192x8192
- New UV maps

[image]

Thank you

Comment: ... maybe you baked with some object that is hidden now? ... if you attach couch into a new blend and bake it again does it happen too? Also there is more wrong things in the scene https://imgur.com/VkKcx3G ... btw couch shading (seen on right-blue screen) doesn't seems to look good ...

Comment: @vklidu thank you for your input. I will check